# How to build a smart bezier curve?

Tags: bezier

Demo Image : http://i.picpar.com/bzH.png

I want to build a smart bezier curve like this. There are 100 targets (grid) in the map. I know the source point (Rocket), and the target point (Grid). How to calculate two control points to build a beautiful bezier curve which can not across the blue map?

Comment: What does "a beautiful bezier curve which can not across the blue map" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Find curve [bounding box](http://goo.gl/1dBYUY) and then check if it is contained in blue map rectangle. If it will be outside move control points respectively.

Assuming that you are using cubic Bezier curve (4 control points) for first try You might set some default coordinates of curve control points:

P1(p0.x-10,p0.y+10)

P2(p3.x-10,p3.y+10)

I do not know what language/libraries You are using but it might have Rectangle.Contains(Bezier.BoundingBox) function which might make things easier.